# React native Android permission from settings

Tags: android, react-native, android-permissions

I am using React native maps for my app and I am using PermissionsAndroid from react-native.

For user current location tracking  I am using [react-native-geolocation-service](https://github.com/Agontuk/react-native-geolocation-service) package. When the app run for the first time, I want to show the Android user do they want to give the location permission. **My first issue was it never ask me the location permission in Android**. It automatically granted the location permission. I don't know why.

If user don't give the permission. then it will save it to the local state a string. I have created one button, if user does not give permission the user will click the button and it will navigate to the Android, settings option. In here the problem is  after giving the permission from android settings, i don't know how to update my local state. as result the button is always navigate me to the `Android` device settings.

**This is my AndroidManifest.xml set up**

```js
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
 

      <meta-data
     android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
     android:value="API KEY"/>
```

**This is my all code**

```js
import React, {useState, useEffect, useRef, useCallback} from 'react';

import Geolocation from 'react-native-geolocation-service';

import {
  Platform,
  PermissionsAndroid,
  Linking,
  Alert,
  Text,
  View,
  StyleSheet,
  Button,
} from 'react-native';

import MapView from 'react-native-maps';

// Initial state
const initialState = {
  latitude: 60.38879664415455,
  longitude: 24.33366230104724,
  latitudeDelta: 5,
  longitudeDelta: 5,
};

export default function App() {
  const [locationPermission, setLocationPermission] = useState('');
  const [location, setLocation] = useState(initialState);

  const mapRef = useRef<Map>(null);

  const animateToRegion = useCallback(() => {
    if (location?.longitudeDelta) {
      mapRef?.current?.animateToRegion(location, 1000);
    }
  }, [location]);

  useEffect(() => {
    animateToRegion();
  }, [location, animateToRegion]);

  const hasPermissionIOS = async () => {
    const status = await Geolocation.requestAuthorization('whenInUse');

    if (status === 'granted') {
      setLocationPermission('granted');
      return true;
    }

    if (status === 'denied') {
      setLocationPermission('denied');
    }

    return false;
  };

  const hasLocationPermission = async () => {
    if (Platform.OS === 'ios') {
      const hasPermission = await hasPermissionIOS();
      return hasPermission;
    }

    const hasPermission = await PermissionsAndroid.check(
      PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
    );

    if (hasPermission) {
      return true;
    }

    try {
      const granted = await PermissionsAndroid.request(
        PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
        {
          title: 'this app wants to access your current location',
          message:
            'Cool Photo App needs access to your camera ' +
            'so you can take awesome pictures.',
          buttonNeutral: 'Ask Me Later',
          buttonNegative: 'Cancel',
          buttonPositive: 'OK',
        },
      );
      if (granted === PermissionsAndroid.RESULTS.GRANTED) {
        setLocationPermission('granted');
        console.log('You can use the location');
      } else {
        console.log('Camera permission denied');
        setLocationPermission('denied');
      }
    } catch (err) {
      console.warn(err);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const hasPermission = hasLocationPermission();

    if (!hasPermission) {
      return;
    }
    // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
  }, []);

  const locationButton = () => {
    if (locationPermission === 'denied') {
      if (Platform.OS === 'ios') {
        const openSetting = () => {
          Linking.openSettings().catch(() => {
            Alert.alert('Unable to open settings');
          });
        };
        Alert.alert(
          'Turn on Location Services to allow s-kaupat to determine your location.',
          '',
          [{text: 'Go to Settings', onPress: openSetting}, {text: 'Dismiss'}],
        );
      } else {
        // android setting
        Linking.openSettings();
      }
    } else {
      console.log('you are good to go');
    }
  };

  const onMapReady = useCallback(async () => {
    const hasPermission = await hasLocationPermission();

    if (!hasPermission) {
      return;
    }

    Geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
      position => {
        const {latitude, longitude} = position.coords;
        if (location) {
          setLocation({
            latitude,
            longitude,
            longitudeDelta: 0.4,
            latitudeDelta: 0.4,
          });
        }
      },
      error => {
        // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
        console.log(error);
      },

      {
        accuracy: {
          android: 'high',
          ios: 'best',
        },
        enableHighAccuracy: true,
        timeout: 15000,
        maximumAge: 10000,
        distanceFilter: 0,
      },
    );
    // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
  }, []);

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <MapView
        style={styles.mapStyle}
        initialRegion={initialState}
        ref={mapRef}
        showsUserLocation={true}
        showsMyLocationButton={false}
        userInterfaceStyle={'light'}
        onMapReady={onMapReady}
        renderToHardwareTextureAndroid={true}
      />
      <Text style={styles.paragraph}>Location permission</Text>
      <Button title="permission" onPress={locationButton} />
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    paddingTop: '10%',
    backgroundColor: '#ecf0f1',
    padding: 8,
  },
  paragraph: {
    margin: 24,
    fontSize: 18,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    textAlign: 'center',
  },
  mapStyle: {
    height: '60%',
  },
});
```